# Django authenticate with python-requests

Tags: django, post, python-requests

Having trouble sorting out how to correctly authenticate a `python-request` client against a django app to permit `POST`.  Our code tries to login first, and then use our established `python-request` session to `POST` data, but our `POST` request is always unauthenticated.

Here's what we are trying

```
# client.py
LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost/accounts/login'
ADD_URL = 'http://localhost/add'

import requests
rqst = requests.session()
rsp = rqst.get(LOGIN_URL)

token = rsp.cookies['csrftoken']
rsp = rqst.post(LOGIN_URL, auth=(uname, pwd),
        data={'csrfmiddlewaretoken':token, 'next':'/'})
# at this point, rsp.status_code == 200 and we are logged in

payload = {'foo':'bar', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':token}
rsp = rqst.post(ADD_URL, json=payload)
# Error -- this post always returns 403 -> HttpResponseForbidden
```

---

```
# view.py
def view_add(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseForbidden('not authenticated')
    ...
```

We have enabled django sessions in `settings.py`. We have no problem accessing `GET` views using this same pattern. Its only `POST` where we are having trouble.

Any ideas, pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by my confusion about django authentication.  Django authentication is forms based, whereas the `rqst.post(..., auth=(uname, pwd))` is [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) by default.

The error was therefore in the first invocation of `rqst.post()`. The corrected code client.py is:

```
# client.py
LOGIN_URL = 'http://localhost/accounts/login'
ADD_URL = 'http://localhost/add'

import requests
rqst = requests.session()
rsp = rqst.get(LOGIN_URL)

token = rsp.cookies['csrftoken']
rsp = rqst.post(LOGIN_URL, 
        data={'username':uname, 'password': pwd,  # <---- HERE IS FIX
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken':token, 'next':'/'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second POST request doesn't have a CSRF token (even if the login request does).

Unless your view is marked `@csrf_exempt`, all non-GET requests require the CSRF token.

Comment: I wish it was that easy. Unfortunately, even after adding `csrfmiddlewaretoken` to second POST I get the same results. I even tried adding the `@csrf_exempt` decorator, but still the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add that user590028's example helped me, but it's important for some reason to add the / after your LOGIN_URL, if that's how your server is set up.

**In my project's urls.py:**

```py
    urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    ]
```

Thus, this didn't work:  http://localhost:8000/login  <-- no slash!

This worked:  http://localhost:8000/login/

... it took me a long time to figure this out, so I hope this helps someone else.

Also - there's a very good Python scraping article that also helped me find the csrf token:
https://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

I have had issues with requests.sessions before with my django projects. I am sure it is doable, but I found it easier to use Selenium as a headless browser. There is very good python support for selenium and it is pretty straight-forward to get started with it.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/